# Selecting Text in PDF file (iphone)

Tags: iphone

I'am working in a PDF reader for iphone and
I want to learn how to Select a text in PDF,
I was able to parse a PDF Document(using CGPDFContentStreamRef and CGPDFScannerRef), and to search for words in the pdf file, but i can't highlight  the word in the PDF Document.
So, how can I locate a word in the PDF View and How to select it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try PDFKitten. There is some code in it.

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGPDFDocumentRef doc = CGPDFDocumentRetain(self.document);
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, 1);

    // Transform the CTM compensating for flipped coordinate system
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw PDF (scaled to fit)
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, YES));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);

    for (Selection *s in self.selections)
    {
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, [s transform]);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, [s frame]);

        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    }

    CGPDFDocumentRelease(doc); doc = nil;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, how can I use this code for highlighting on touch?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried FastPDFKit?

https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit

It will highlight the search results, but won't let you select text by touching.

Comment: @user441298: Did you try this?

Comment: can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335799/is-there-any-framework-to-highlight-text-on-pdf-file-after-rendering-in-iphone